# JavaScript anonymous function task

Tags: javascript

So I have a simple js task here.

Given:

```
function test() {alert(1);};
```

What I've got to do to make the following work?

```
test.test()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Test is an object in this case

Comment: What do you mean by work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting `test` to have a reference to itself:

```
function test() { alert(1); }
test.test = test;

test(); // alerts 1
test.test(); // alerts 1
test.test.test(); // etc.
```

`Function`s in JavaScript are a type of `Object`, so they can be given properties as well.

---

Or, you can create an `Object` to hold the `Function` in a property:

```
var test = {
    test: function () { alert(1); }
};

test.test(); // alerts 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` is an object, so you have to make an object

```
function test() {
    this.test = function() {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Or, make a prototype function to save memory.

```
test.prototype = {
    test : function() {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt this is actually what you want to do, but I'll offer that functions in JavaScript are objects just like any other and can have properties, including properties that reference (and have the same name as) the function itself:

```
function test() {
    alert(1);
}

test.test = test;
test.test();
```

I have no idea why you'd want to do this.